# WCF over MSMQ, 403 Service unavailable

Tags: wcf, msmq

I setup a WCF service to work over HTTP and [MSMQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing). It kind of works. The HTTP protocol works 100%. The problem is with `net.msmq`. When I check the queue, the messages have gone down by 1 which I assume means it's being processed. But at the same time, the service is no longer available. I receive a 403 service unavailable error from [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services). When I purge the queue and reset the site, the service is available again.

Message queue has full permissions for everyone and the service doesn't do anything (seriously, it's just a stub method) so it isn't a code problem.

The contract is marked as one way and the action is `*`.

Messages are going into the queue (sending 10 at a time) and at least 1 message is getting pulled (count goes down to 9).

The `net.msmq` listener service is running.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure but might be it has to do something with Service throtlling

Comment: thanks, but it happens even if I only send 1 message.

Comment: Ok i thought its the "heavy load" which could be causing problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, because I forgot to specify the bindingConfiguration. I had the binding setup like

```
<bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="Msmq" exactlyOnce="true" >
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
      </bindings>
```

Once I realized the bindingConfiguration was missing from my endpoint, I added it in, and it started working correctly.

```
<endpoint address ="net.msmq://localhost/private/MyQueue.svc"
                  binding="netMsmqBinding"
                  contract="IService" bindingConfiguration="Msmq">
```